# IPC V client/server application with shared memory and a file as database, written on C

Tags: c, pointers, ipc, shared-memory

I still can't wrap my head around this problem... I have an implementation of a client/server application using **shared memory** as a way of communication. However, I'm trying to use a local file that serves as a database for the server-side. What I'm guessing that it goes something like this: 
- when the **client** wants something, he makes a request to the **server** (let's say, "print me the name of John, if you have a John in the database". The **server** then searches the database and returns the char-sequence of John who apparently has a client number of 123456789 and then the **client** prints it. The real problem occurs when the client tries to read this - I can't understand how he must get the information from the server and use it as he likes.

At the moment I'm using temp file as a database but I can't even make it work with it either. I get **Segmentation fault** when the client tries reading from the database. I really want to understand how is it possible to read a local file to the server and use it as a database and then work with that database, when the client start making requests and as a result, pass data to the client.

Any help will be much appreciated..

Definitions:

```
#define  SERVER_BUSY    0
#define  SERVER_READY   1
#define  DATA_CONSUMED  2
#define  REQUEST        3
#define  BUSY           4

#define  SEARCH 0
#define  GETALL 1
#define  INSERT 2

#define MAX 100

struct SharedMemory {
    int  requestType;
    int  processId;
    int  status;
    char names[1];
    int  fakNums[1];
    int  count;
};
```

Here is my server implementation:

```
void  main(int  argc, char *argv[]) {
     key_t          sharedMemoryKey;
     int            sharedMemoryId;
     struct SharedMemory  *sharedMemoryPointer;

     sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".", 'x'); 
     sharedMemoryId = shmget(sharedMemoryKey, sizeof(struct SharedMemory), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
     if (sharedMemoryId < 0) {
          printf("SERVER ERROR\n");
          exit(1);
     }

     sharedMemoryPointer = (struct SharedMemory *) shmat(sharedMemoryId, NULL, 0);
     if ((int) sharedMemoryPointer == -1) {
          printf("SHARED MEMERY ERROR\n");
          exit(1);
     }

     printf("ATTACHED TO SHARED MEMORY...\n");

     printf("START CLIENT...\n");
    //temp data
    int totalCount = 1;
    struct SharedMemory sharedMem;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
        sharedMem.names[i] = "NAME";
        sharedMem.fakNums[i] = i;
    }
    //-temp data  

     sharedMemoryPointer->status = SERVER_READY;
     while (1) {
    if  (sharedMemoryPointer->status != REQUEST) {
            sleep(1);
    } else {
        printf("START WORKING...\n");
        sharedMemoryPointer->status = SERVER_BUSY;
        int requestType = sharedMemoryPointer->requestType;
        switch (requestType) {
            case SEARCH : {
                int pos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                    if (strcmp(sharedMem.names[i], sharedMemoryPointer->names[0]) == 0){
                        strcpy(sharedMemoryPointer->names[pos], sharedMem.names[i]);
                        sharedMemoryPointer->fakNums[pos] =  sharedMem.fakNums[i];
                        pos++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                sharedMemoryPointer->count = pos;
                break;
                }
            case GETALL : {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
                    strcpy(sharedMemoryPointer->names[i], sharedMem.names[i]);
                    sharedMemoryPointer->fakNums[i] =  sharedMem.fakNums[i];
                }
                sharedMemoryPointer->count = totalCount;
                break;
                }
            case INSERT : {
                strcpy(sharedMem.names[totalCount], sharedMemoryPointer->names[0]);
                sharedMem.fakNums[totalCount] = sharedMemoryPointer->fakNums[0];
                totalCount; 
                break;
                }

        } 

        int clientPid = sharedMemoryPointer->processId;
        printf("WAKE UP THE PROCESS...\n");
        kill(clientPid, SIGCONT);

        sharedMemoryPointer->status = SERVER_READY;
    }
     }
}
```

Here is my client implementation:

```
void onServerReady();

key_t          sharedMemoryKey;
int            sharedMemoryId;
struct SharedMemory  *sharedMemoryPointer;

bool isSearching = false;
bool isInserting = false;
bool isFetchingAll = false;

void  main(int  argc, char *argv[]) {

     //init

     char* SEARCHARG =  "-s";
     char* INSERTARG =  "-i";
     char* LISTARG   =  "-l";

     sharedMemoryKey = ftok(".", 'x');
     sharedMemoryId = shmget(sharedMemoryKey, sizeof(struct SharedMemory), 0666);
     if (sharedMemoryId < 0) {
          printf("SHARED MEMORY ERROR\n");
          exit(1);
     }

     sharedMemoryPointer = (struct SharedMemory *) shmat(sharedMemoryId, NULL, 0);
     if ((int) sharedMemoryPointer == -1) {
          printf("*** shmat error (client) ***\n");
          exit(1);
     }
     printf("   CLIENT ATTACHED TO SHARED MEMORY\n");

     signal(SIGCONT, onServerReady);

     //set our request
     if (argc < 2) {
        printf("  NO ARGS. EXITING\n");
    exit(1);
     }

     if (strcmp(argv[1], SEARCHARG) == 0) {
    isSearching = true;
    if (argc < 3) {
            printf("  NOT ENOUGH ARGS. EXITING\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    while (sharedMemoryPointer->status != SERVER_READY) {
        sleep(1);
    } 
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = BUSY;
    sharedMemoryPointer->processId = getpid();
    sharedMemoryPointer->requestType = SEARCH;
    strcpy(sharedMemoryPointer->names[0], argv[2]);
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = REQUEST;
     } else if (strcmp(argv[1], LISTARG) == 0) {
    isFetchingAll = true;
    while (sharedMemoryPointer->status != SERVER_READY) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = BUSY;
    sharedMemoryPointer->processId = getpid();
    sharedMemoryPointer->requestType = GETALL;
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = REQUEST;
     } else if (strcmp(argv[1], INSERTARG) == 0) {
    isInserting = true;
    if (argc < 4) {
            printf("  NOT ENOUGH ARGS. EXITING\n");
        exit(1);
        }
    while (sharedMemoryPointer->status != SERVER_READY) {
        sleep(1);
    } 
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = BUSY;
    sharedMemoryPointer->processId = getpid();
    sharedMemoryPointer->requestType = INSERT;
    strcpy(sharedMemoryPointer->names[0], argv[2]);
    sharedMemoryPointer->fakNums[0] = atoi(argv[3]);
    sharedMemoryPointer->status = REQUEST;
     }

     //wait
     pause();

     //while (sharedMemoryPointer->status != FILLED)
     //     ;
    // printf("   Client found the data is ready...\n");
     //printf("   Client found %d %d %d %d in shared memory...\n",
         //       sharedMemoryPointer->data[0], sharedMemoryPointer->data[1], 
       //         sharedMemoryPointer->data[2], sharedMemoryPointer->data[3]);

    // sharedMemoryPointer->status = TAKEN;
    // printf("   Client has informed server data have been taken...\n");
    // shmdt((void *) sharedMemoryPointer);
   //  printf("   Client has detached its shared memory...\n");
    // printf("   Client exits...\n");
    // exit(0);
}

void onServerReady() {
    if (isFetchingAll || isSearching) {
        int count = sharedMemoryPointer->count;
printf("\n %d", count);
        //for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //  printf("Name %s, fakNum %d \n", sharedMemoryPointer->names[i], sharedMemoryPointer->fakNums[i]);            
        //}
    } else {
        printf("\nSuccessfull insertion!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the problems _gpeche_ addressed in his helpful answer, this doesn't sound like a good job for sysv shm. You should use something message oriented, either system v message queues, or perhaps even better unix domain sockets, udp and the like

Answer (score 2):

My C is a bit rusty, but it looks as if your `SharedMemory` struct (that resides in SysV shared memory) is being loaded with pointers to `Data` in non-shared memory (allocated via `malloc`, or statically inside the private memory space of the process) That is not going to work at the other side, because:

- the pointed-to memory is still private and not shared.
- even if it were shared, its memory address would probably be different in the memory map of each process (that is, the shared memory block could be at, say, addr=1000 in the server and addr=2000 in the client; writing "1000" at one side is going to point to a wrong place at the other side)

You should use `shmget` to allocate a block of memory big enough to hold everything  that you want to share and then put all the information inside that block. Avoid pointers, embed the info in your shared memory struct.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, when I try to embed the info in my struct `SharedMemory { char names[20] }` the shmget() method doesn't work. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have updated my code. Can you please guide me how to make the array of Student infromation (name and number as strings) and load them from a file?

Comment: @Calihog You should add your struct definitions to the question, it is difficult to know what is going on without knowing those.

Comment: yes sorry. I have added the definitions in the post above!